# Play 2 asynchronous Promise redeeming

Tags: java, csv, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

I am researching using Play's asynchronous features to perform a parallelizable task but from all the documentation, books and articles I've been able to find, I cannot figure out how to *know* an asynchronous task has been completed so perhaps I am misunderstanding a critical piece of information or am using the wrong tools for the job.

Essentially, I need to construct a hierarchical object graph from a number of flat CSVs and as it turns out, reading these CSVs can be done in parallel. However, as I am reading through the CSVs, I am doing it in chunks and I need each "worker" (processing a CSV) to stop, remember their position within the CSV and report back `Result` to the Coordinator so that when all workers have reported back with their chunks, I know I have the hierarchical object fully processed and can do something else with it at the same time letting the workers continue on until each of them has reached the end of a CSV they had been reading.

Is there a way to know a `Promise` has been converted to a `Result`? Do I need to poll the `Promise` or can I query it in a fashion similar to Java's `ExecutorService.isDone()`? What documentation would you suggest - it seems all the books on Play Framework die fast, as the API is quickly changing between minor versions (e.g. `Akka.future()` -> `Promise.promise()` or `Promise.waitAll()` -> `Promise.sequence()`, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure which Promie/Future library are you using.  Is it scala's one or the akka's one?

Comment: I am using the Play one - from `play.libs.F.Promise`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can use `promise.get(timeout)` to wait for the promise, it isn't the recommanded way.
A better way to use it is to map it to another promise to do another processing using the 'map' method:

```
Promise<String> strPromise = Promise.pure("10");
Promise<Integer> intPromise = strPromise.map(new Function<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String arg0) throws Throwable {
        return Integer.valueOf(arg0);
    }
});
```

The map function have two types one is the input value which is the value of the 'strPromise' promise (String) and one is the output with will be the value of the new promise (Integer).
If, and only if the promise complete successfully the map function will be invoked. So the 'intPromise ' will hold either the success value or the failure.

If you need to return Response then you should use the [Play Async](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync). The last promise should be the Result and play will take care of it.
If you need to do something else with the promise, which (for any reason) should not be in another promise you can listen to the onRedeem for success and onFailure for errors:

```
intPromise.onRedeem(new Callback<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void invoke(Integer arg0) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Promiss redeemed: " + arg0);
    }
});
intPromise.onFailure(new Callback<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void invoke(Throwable arg0) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(arg0);
    }
});
```

Note that if you are using Java 8 you can use lambdas to make it more readable.